# Product naming convention for iPhone 4 apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad, naming, conventions

With the iPad we got applications with the product name extension "HD" to distinguish them from their low resolution iPhone counterparts. But, now with iPhone 4 also being an "HD" device, how to correctly name your apps?

Basically I'd like to publish a game in three flavors: iPad, iPhone 4, and all other iPhone/iPod devices.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a branding question, and is not really related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Why name them differently; unless there are major functionality differences just make an app that works on all three devices at the best resolution available.

However, the iPad and the iPhone versions might be very different. In this case I'd go for one version targeting both iPhones (called MyGame) and one for the iPad (called MyGame HD).

It's what Angry Birds have done and it's pretty clear what they mean.

However, I'd go for one universal app if possible.

Comment: Angry birds does not have a hires iPhone 4 version AFAIK, just the regular lo-res version tested for iOS4, so they have no solution for this.

A proper iPhone 4 version needs a different graphics bundle as it has 4 times more pixels than other iPhones, that would add more than 20mb of weight added to a regular version in my case. Not very elegant.

I'm considering making an universal version for iPad and iPhone 4, both in HD flavor, but that also seems a bit unlogical to separate iPhone 4 from the other iPhones and selling it together with iPad games. :)

Comment: Ah, I thought angrybirds had resources for both iphones but I think you're right - it's using some sort of smoothing to make it look OK (probably openGL's upscaling textures) And you're right; 20MB extra resource seems a bit excessive!

Comment: You could solve it by making it a marketing thing - have more features for the iPhone 4 version, call it 'MyGame delux' and sell it for more ;)